# A second look at Java Code, may I get a accurate explanation on bolded?

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class PhoneInfo {
    String name;
    String phoneNumber;
    String birth;

    public PhoneInfo(String name, String num, String birth) {
        this.name = name;
        phoneNumber = num;
        this.birth = birth;
    }

    public PhoneInfo(String name, String num) {
        this.name = name;
        phoneNumber = num;
        this.birth = null;
    }

    public void showPhoneInfo() {
        System.out.println("name : " + name);
        System.out.println("phone : " + phoneNumber);
        if (birth != null)
            System.out.println("birth : " + birth);

        System.out.println("");
    }

}

class PhoneBookManager {
    final int MAX_CNT = 100;
    PhoneInfo[] infoStorage = new PhoneInfo[MAX_CNT];
    int curCnt = 0;

    public void inputData() {
        System.out.println("Start Data Entry..");
        System.out.print("Name : ");
        String name = MenuViewer.keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Phone Number : ");
        String phone = MenuViewer.keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Date Of Birth : ");
        String birth = MenuViewer.keyboard.nextLine();

        infoStorage[curCnt++] = new PhoneInfo(name, phone, birth);
        System.out.println("Data Entry is Finished. \n");
    }

    public void searchData() {
        System.out.println("Data Search Begins.");
        System.out.print("Name : ");
        String name = MenuViewer.keyboard.nextLine();

        int dataIdx = search(name);
        if (dataIdx < 0) {
            System.out.println("The Data does not exist. \n");
        } else {
            infoStorage[dataIdx].showPhoneInfo();
            System.out.println("Data Search is finished. \n");

        }
    }

    public void deleteData() {
        System.out.println("Data delete starts..");

        System.out.print(" Name : ");
        String name = MenuViewer.keyboard.nextLine();

        int dataIdx = search(name);
        if (dataIdx < 0) {
            System.out.println("Data does not exist. \n");
        } else {
            //Begin of code for explanation
            for (int idx=dataIdx;idx<(curCnt-1);idx++)
                infoStorage[idx]=infoStorage[idx + 1];
            curCnt--; //Clear Explanation would be great!//
            //End of code for explanation
            System.out.println("Data Deletion Complete. ");
        }
    }

    private int search(String name) {
        for (int idx = 0; idx < curCnt; idx++) {

            PhoneInfo curInfo = infoStorage[idx];
            if (name.compareTo(curInfo.name) == 0)
                return idx;
        }
        return -1;
    }

}
```

This part is a real confuser for me, an obstacle in my java learning experience it would be great if one can explain this to me like I am less than a 10 year old. I have such a vague idea on how this is operating, therefore baby step by step explanation from experts would be a great source of learning for me!

```
for (int idx=dataIdx;idx<(curCnt-1);idx++)
    infoStorage[idx]=infoStorage[idx + 1];
curCnt--;
```

Comment: for (int idx=dataIdx;idx<(curCnt-1);idx++)
            infoStorage[idx]=infoStorage[idx + 1];
        curCnt--;

Comment: Above is what I need explanation for :)

Comment: That's an array item removal...

Comment: @user3547430 Don't post code in comments. It's entirely unreadable. Instead, edit your original question to include the (properly formatted!) code.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart the code is there, missing in the wall of code posted by OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The piece of code that you want/need an explanation for:

```
for (int idx=dataIdx;idx<(curCnt-1);idx++)
    infoStorage[idx]=infoStorage[idx + 1];
curCnt--;
//adding this line as well
System.out.println("Data Deletion Complete. ");
```

The code above is meant to remove an item in the array:

```
for (int idx=dataIdx;idx<(curCnt-1);idx++)
    //passing the elements in the array to a previous position
    infoStorage[idx]=infoStorage[idx + 1];
```

Note that this `for` loop doesn't have any braces, so it only affects the statement next to it. It is better to write it as:

```
for (int idx=dataIdx;idx<(curCnt-1);idx++) {
    //passing the elements in the array to a previous position
    infoStorage[idx]=infoStorage[idx + 1];
}
```

For better code readability.

After the `for` loop execution, the line below decreases the current array size handler by 1:

```
curCnt--;
```

After item removal from the array, showing a *nice* message to user:

```
System.out.println("Data Deletion Complete. ");
```

---

Note that `++` and `--` operators affect the current value of the variable: the former increases its value and the latter decreases it. For example, this code:

```
idx++
```

Is *similar* to write

```
idx = idx + 1;
```

More info on this:

- [Java Tutorials: Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Comment: @user3547430 *therefore infostorage becomes 1* this would be *`infostorage[0]` would have the value of `infostorage[1]`*.

Comment: the next run of the for loop would start idx with a value of 2 because of idx++ and idx + 1?

Comment: @user3547430 the `for` loop without braces only affects to the single statement next to it, so it will execute `infoStorage[idx]=infoStorage[idx + 1];` only, after the `for` loop execution, it will execute `curCnt--;`.

Comment: InfoStorage[0] = InfoStorage[0+1], therefore infoStorage[0] would have the value of [1] now, Okay I see it now but then that 1 is idx therefore idx++ would add one more to it being 2 for the next run for the loop am I correct?

Comment: @user3547430 no, only `++` affects the current value of the variable. `idx+1` won't affect its value, it generates a new value, that's all.

Comment: therefore, the next for will start with 1, the idx++ has nothing to do with idx+1 value.

Comment: would not curCnt-1 be same as curCnt--?

Comment: @user3547430 no, `--` affects the value of the variable (similar to `++`), but `curCnt - 1` does nothing.

Comment: okay its just a mock, it doesn't actually affect the variable itself right?

Comment: okay I think that solves everything I have the data now I have to just ingest them in a logical sense. Thank you Luiggi!

Comment: @user3547430 you're welcome. If this post solved your problem, please mark it as the answer by clicking on the check below the reputation.

Comment: took a while to find that check box! haha thank you!

Comment: one more question actually, the curCNT-1, if the total curCNT is 8 then its 7, would that value carry over to the next for loop? or it would stay 7, for example in the next loop it will become 6.

Comment: @user3547430 it will stay as 7 until it is updated again, by adding a new element (curCnt++) or removing an element (curCnt--).

Comment: are you still there? I actually have one more question, why is curCNT-1, the minus one necessary?

Comment: @user3547430 because if your array has 1 element (curCnt = 1), then you should traverse the array from the base position (0) until the size of the array minus 1 (curCnt - 1).

Comment: so the minus one technically just points out [0] of array because idx is in a form of array  to be compared with idx, curCNT needs to be in form of array and the only way for curCNT to express its form to an array type is by minus one

Comment: @nakkim1 an array is not the same that an `int`. `int idx` is an `int` variable used as index to access to the elements in the array. The array is like a giant box where you can store elements and find them by their index, which is 0-based.

Comment: if the whole program exists only one name file, meaning only 1 element would the curCNT be read as [0], or with curCNT=1?

Comment: @nakkim1 it will have `curCnt = 1` and a single element stored in `infoStorage[0]`.

Comment: Okay great thank you again its really great to have a experienced user beside me, I've just been hanging on to this problem for 2 days and bam in couple of hours all is done this is really great!!Thanks again!